# Implementing arrays in Z3 timeout

Tags: arrays, timeout, z3

I'm trying to implement my own version of arrays in Z3, called "Records". They're just Arrays which are indexed by strings. I keep receiving a timeout for the code below and I can't figure out why. I know I could just use normal arrays but I'd like to determine the problem with this code.

I have an assertion for each of the basic array select/store axioms. any idea as to what's wrong?

```
(declare-sort Record)

(declare-fun storeR (Record String Int) Record)
(declare-fun selectR (Record String) Int)

;selct/store axioms for records
(assert (forall ((r Record)(s String)(i Int)) 
  (= (selectR (storeR r s i) s) i)))
(assert (forall ((r Record)(s String)(q String) (i Int)) 
  (or (= s q) (= (selectR (storeR r s i) q) (selectR r q) ))))
(assert (forall ((r Record)(q Record))
  (=> (forall ((s String)) (= (selectR r s) (selectR q s)))  (= r q))))


 (declare-const r Record)
 (assert (= (selectR r "number") 1))
 (check-sat)
```

Answer (score 0):

Start the file with the following two lines:

```
   (set-option :smt.auto_config false)
   (set-option :smt.mbqi       false)
```

Then Z3 returns "unknown". With mbqi, z3 tries (and fails) to find a model.

Comment: Hm, do you have any idea why it would fail? Aren't these just the canonical array select/store axioms?